# MacBook Air 2020 does not support 100hz display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

The display is samsung C34H89x, ultrawide 100hz. I'm connecting it with USB-C and my MacBook Pro supports 100hz, but the air does not. Is that a limitation of the air?

Answer (score 1):

According to MacTracker (fan, not affiliated) the Macbook Air (retina, 13inch, 2018) supports:

> One external display with 5120 by 2880 resolution at up to 60 Hz, Up to two external displays with 4096 by 2304 resolution at up to 60 Hz

The 2020 air is as follows:

> One external 6K display with 6016 by 3384 resolution at 60 Hz, one external 5K display with 5120 by 2880 resolution at 60 Hz, up to two external 4K displays with 4096 by 2304 resolution at up to 60 Hz

So not 100Hz.

Comment: On my monitor I have a setting for DP ver. 1.1 or 1.2. I swapped back and forth a couple of times and it started working at 100hz, no idea how or why.